# Notepad delete duplicate lines

Tags: notepad++

How do I delete duplicate lines in notepad++?  I see some examples but many are many years old and solutions do not now work.

[image]

Say I had:

```
Example
Example
1
1
3
```

Desired:

```
Example
1
3
```

I do not appear to have plugin manager in 32 bit notepad++ or TextFx Tools

Comment: Please show what you've tried and how exactly they didn't work. Otherwise somebody may suggest the same.

Comment: What about this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16293580/4721734

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have provided several possible solutions for your consideration. Please forgive me if I go over anything you already know. =)

**TL;DR**

As of Notepad++ v7.7.1, Notepad++ has a feature called *Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines* which does the same thing as the other two solutions given below (i.e. it removes consecutive duplicate lines).

It can be accessed with *Edit → Line Operations → Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines*.

---

*See [Bartleby's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1646425/302907) below for an example of a regular expression that will deduplicate lines without sorting.*

---

**Original Answer**

Per the comment by @máté-juhász, the accepted answer to this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad/16293580#16293580) will work with your example data.

In essence:

- Open *Search → Replace...* ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> ) in Notepad++.
- Under the "Find what:" field, enter the following [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

  ```
   ^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)
  ```
- Leave the "Replace with:" field blank and make sure to mark "Regular expression" under the "Search Mode" options.
- Once you are ready to remove your lines, click "Replace All".

Note that the original answer seems to indicate that the `. matches newline` option should be checked but some people in the comments apparently had better luck leaving it unchecked. For your data, I left it unchecked and it seemed to work well.

*ex. Using Regular Expressions*

[image: Regex Replacement Example]

---

**Using uniq**

As an alternative, assuming no other option suites your needs, if you have a Windows port of the Unix-based [uniq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq) utility, you could possibly integrate this into your workflow with Notepad++.

In short, `uniq` performs the same function as the regular expression above but in a potentially more reliable fashion. The downside is that incorporating it with Notepad++ is a bit of a hack. With that in mind, if you wish to give it a go, the basic steps are outlined below.

*Getting uniq*

To begin, you need a copy of `uniq` for Windows. There may be several options available to you but, for simplicity, I might suggest the [GnuWin32 CoreUtils package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) which includes `uniq`. You can currently download a [lightweight installer](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/coreutils.php) if you opt not to download and combine the zipped versions of the CoreUtils package components yourself.

As a tip, for every step in the solution involving `uniq`, I would skip using paths with spaces. Unix often treats spaces in directory names differently than Windows, so utilities ported from that environment may have issues with them.

---

*For reference, I am not sure what (if any) file size limits might apply to the GnuWin32 build of `uniq`, but I often use it for text files with at least several megabytes of data (often several hundred thousand lines) with ease.*

---

*Using uniq With Notepad++*

Once `uniq` is installed, place something similar to the following lines in a batch file:

```
C:\path\to\uniq.exe %* > C:\temp\uniq_tmp.txt
notepad++ C:\temp\uniq_tmp.txt
exit()
```

Save this batch file in a permanent directory you are comfortable with. For reference purposes, I will call this *uniq_npp.bat*. Note that "temp" can be any folder, but "tmp" and "temp" often exist on Windows already. Likewise, "uniq_tmp.txt" can be any name you wish, so long as it is used consistently.

After saving *uniq_npp.bat*, we are then ready to integrate its functionality into Notepad++. To do this, open the Notepad++ *Run...* menu ( <kbd>F5</kbd> ) and enter something similar to the following into the field that appears:

```
cmd /k C:\path\to\uniq_npp.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

You can test your Notepad++ command before saving it if you click the left-most "Run" button.

*ex. Run... Dialog*

[image: Run Dialog Example]

Otherwise, click "Save..." and name your command appropriately. You can give it a keyboard shortcut if you care to but it isn't required. Click "OK" to retain your command settings and place it in the *Run...* dropdown menu for later use.

*ex. Run Dropdown Menu*

[image: Run Menu Entry Example]

---

*Assuming it interests you, I have a very brief overview of the details of how the `uniq` solution works in the "Notes" section at the end of this answer.*

---

*Caveats*

One important thing to remember about this solutions with `uniq` is that it *absolutely requires* a path to a file saved on disk (the document cannot be open in just Notepad++ alone).

This isn't an issue with an existing file you've opened, but if you create a new file or alter an existing original, you need to *Save* it first before running your *uniq_npp.bat* file. Otherwise, the operation will fail and any new data will not be sorted.

As a small advantage, its probably worth mentioning that this save limitation doesn't apply to the regular expression option above.

---

**Notes**

*Sorting*

The solutions offered (that is, the initial regular expression and `uniq`) both require duplicate lines to appear directly above one another to be removed e.g.:

```
duplicate line X
duplicate line X
```

This means that sorting your data ahead of applying one of these operations is important. I am assuming you are already doing this given your example data, but it's worth mentioning anyway.

*Notepad++ Macros*

As a small suggestion, since Notepad++ doesn't have any actual keyboard shortcuts for its built-in line sorting operations, you may want to record a macro to help with sorting. Particularly, you can record an *Edit → Select All* ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) operation and then choose one of the *Edit → Line Operations → Sort Lines Lexicographically* options.

For the `uniq` solution, it may also be worth considering recording a "Save" operation as the final step to a sorting macro. Also note that the steps for the regular expression option (opening the Replace dialog, entering the regular expression, etc.), can be recorded to a handy macro as well.

*How The uniq Solution Works*

In brief:

- The "Run..." line spawns a command window (`cmd /k`), calls *uniq_npp.bat* and gives it the path to wherever the current file you have selected is stored.
- In *uniq_npp.bat*, this path is captured via the `%*` wildcard passed to `uniq`. The de-duplicated data from `uniq` is then redirected (`>`) to "uniq_tmp.txt".
- Lastly, the batch file opens this cleaned text in a new Notepad++ tab and the command window is closed via `exit()`.

*uniq_npp.bat Improvements (?)*

Regarding sorting, another option is to skip using Notepad++ to sort things all together. You potentially lose some flexibility in the process regarding sorting options, but you can just sort items as an extra step in your batch file via the [Windows sort](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html) command. To add this step, you can modify the first line of *uniq_npp.bat* as follows:

```
sort %* | C:\path\to\uniq.exe > C:\temp\uniq_tmp.txt
```

This simply pipes the sorted data from `sort` to `uniq`. As you can see, `sort` now initially captures the data path, rather than `uniq`.

Another thought is to (possibly) use the `%*` wildcard as part of a string operation to obtain the original file name and replace e.g. "uniq_tmp.txt" with something like "original-filename_uniq.txt" to make it more... unique.

*Potential Pitfalls*

- By default, Windows `sort` will sort numbers as e.g.

  ```
   1
   11
   2
   21
  ```

if they are not preceeded by 0 (e.g. `01, 02, 011, 021`).

- While the GnuWin32 CoreUtils package does come with a port of the [Unix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix)) utility (which has more robust options than Windows `sort`), this particular implementation (unlike most of the GnuWin32 utilites) strikes me as a bit poor on Windows. However, if you use a different Windows port of the Unix version of `sort`, this issue may not apply and might prove to be a better option overall.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that this works nicely for items that are not in order:

Search:
`(?s)^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)`

Click 'Replace All' within with nothing in the 'Replace with:' field.

Edit:

Here is the step by step:

(?s)
Dot also matches newline.

^
Start of line

(.*?)$
Establish the first capture group by matching zero or more of any character, non-greedily, until the first end of line that is encountered.

\s+?
Match one or more whitespace characters, non-greedily

^
Start of line (again)

(?=
Positive lookahead with a non-capturing group (this pattern must be matched, but it is not stored).

.*^\1$)
Match zero or more characters, greedily, continuing until until a new line where the entire line is a match of the first capture group.

So the regex creates a capture group and then searches all lines in the document until it finds one that precisely matches that line and replaces the original line with nothing.

Addendum:  I wasn't thinking of it at the time, and I apologize to the creator of the Regex, but I believe [Scott](https://superuser.com/users/150988/scott-%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%96) is correct in that I was using a very slightly modified version of a regex someone else had created.  If I were to guess to its origin, I think it is probably more likely to be the answer actually credited within the link he gave, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad/16293580#16293580).

So in closing, please accept my apologies for:

1. Not giving credit where it is due.  I wasn't thinking of it at the time, but I should have.
2. Not fully explaining the answer I provided, which would increase someone's understanding of what is happening, so they may be able to use that information toward other problems.
3. Not replying to Scott's comment more quickly.  I'm not terribly expert on the use of this site (hence my low score) and didn't think to check my notifications until today.

Mea culpa!

Comment: This looks a lot like the regular expression part of [Anaksunaman's answer](https://superuser.com/q/1291577/150988#1291823) to this question — which, in turn, *admits* to being a copy of [a much older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3958350/1672723#16293580). Can you explain how it works? In particular, what does the `(?s)` at the beginning do? … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Checking `Wrap around` alleviated a minor annoyance for me where lines might not be processed based on the cursor's starting position in the document. Also, it might be worth explicitly mentioning using `Replace All` (assuming someone doesn't want to step through each match individually).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, but regex and uniq only detected duplicate lines next to each other. Using this awk script instead as awkuniq-npp.bat, it is Notepad++ compatible. 4 line bat file:

```
C:\pathto\awk.exe '(a[$0]++==0)' %* > %*.1
del %*
move %*.1 %*
exit()
```

Command to Run:

```
cmd /k C:\pathto\awkuniq-npp.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

It uses auto-reload after del/move to replace the same filename

Comment: +1. Good stuff! =)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following search/replace regex (after sorting the lines), I find it more intuitive to understand:

`Find: (.*)\r?\n(\1\r?\n)+`

`Replace with: \1\r\n`

Explanation:
 - look for "anything" (a line of text) followed by a new line (\n or \r\n): .*\r?\n

 - keep the content of the line in a variable:  (.*)\r?\n
 - look for re-occurrences of the same line one or more times: (.*)\r?\n(\1\r?\n)+

Replacement:
 - Replace all the above with just the line itself and new line: \1\r\n

Hope it helps,
sb3k

Comment: This will not remove the last line if there're no linebreaks.