# How to delete same lines in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-editing, duplicate

I want to find out if there are any extra files between a long list of files that I generated. Because I`m weak at explaining stuff with words, I'd rather illustrate.

This is an illustration of the list of files that I have inside a Notepad++ session at the moment:
(numerals represent line count)

```
1   gold.txt
2   silver.txt
3   copper.txt
4
5
6   gold.txt
7   silver.txt
8   copper.txt
9   unknown.txt
```

And the following is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9   unknown.txt
```

How to remove everything with an exception of `unknown.txt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad delete duplicate lines](https://superuser.com/questions/1291577/notepad-delete-duplicate-lines)

Comment: @Toto It isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select menu *Edit* > *Line Operations* > *Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending* to sort your file. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to replace the texts like below

- Find what: `^(.*?\R)(\1)+`
- Replace with: empty
- Search mode: regular expression, with the option `. matches newline` unchecked

Then press replace all

[image: Notepad++ sort lines]

This will not leave the `unknown.txt` at the 9th line as your example, but it works

A better solution would be using the TextFX plugin. Just select *TextFX* > Click *TextFX Tools* > Check *+Sort outputs only UNIQUE (at column) lines* then remove the duplicates by selecting *TextFX* > *TextFX Tools* > *Sort lines case insensitive (at column)*

[image: TextFX sort lines]