# Notepad++: How to keep only recurring lines and delete non-repeating lines

Tags: notepad++

Say i had:

```
Example
Example
1
1
3
```

desired:

```
Example
1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Assuming your file is sorted and terminated with an empty line

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+\R)(\1)*`
- Replace with: `$2`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (           # group 1
        .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
        \R          # any kind of linebreak
    )           # end group 1
    (           # group 2
        \1          # backreference to group 1 (i.e. same value as captured in group 1)
    )*          # end group 2, may appear 0 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2, will be empty if there are no duplicates
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The following solution requires that duplicate lines
will be contained in one sequence in the file.

To remove unique lines I found the post
[Find and KEEP all DUPLICATE lines (instead of unique lines) in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727299/find-and-keep-all-duplicate-lines-instead-of-unique-lines-in-a-text-file).

Based on the answer and comments in the post, the following
will remove the unique lines.

In the Find and Replace dialog
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
do this:

**Search what**: `^((.*)\R(\2\R?)+)*\K.*?\n`
**Replace with**: nothing
**Search mode**: Regular expression
**. matches newline** : checked

Click Replace All to delete the unique lines.

For removing duplicate lines, see the post
[Notepad delete duplicate lines](https://superuser.com/questions/1291577/notepad-delete-duplicate-lines).